# Segmentation fault during input of a matrix

Tags: c

So, I have to create a program that, when the user inserts a table, has to send in output only the border of the table. I used a matrix for the input but when the user ends the input, the program stops and I get segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VAL 50

void inputMatrice(int m[VAL][VAL], int *ncol, int *nrig);
void bordi(int m[][VAL], int ncol, int nrig, int v[], int *nv);
void outputVettore(int v[], int nv);

int main(){
    int m[VAL][VAL], v[VAL], *ncol, *nrig, nc, nr, nv;
    ncol = &nc;
    nrig = &nr;
    inputMatrice(m, ncol, nrig);
    nv=0;
    printf("ciao");
    bordi(m, nc, nr, v, &nv);
    outputVettore(v, nv);

}
/*Funzione per input matrici*/

void inputMatrice(int m[VAL][VAL], int *ncol, int *nrig){

    int i=0, j=0;
    printf("Inserisci il numero di righe: ");
    scanf("%d", nrig);
    printf("Inserisci il numero di colonne: ");
    scanf("%d", ncol);
    for(i=0;i<*nrig;i++){
        for(j=0;j<*ncol;j++){
            printf("Inserisci i valori della tabella nella posizione %d,%d: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void bordi(int m[][VAL], int ncol, int nrig, int v[], int *nv){
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    for(j=1; j<ncol; j++){
        v[k]=m[i][j];
        *nv++;
    }
    for(i=1;i<nrig;i++){
        v[k] = m[i][j];
        *nv++;
    }
    for(j=(ncol-1); j>0; j++){
        v[k]=m[i][j];
        *nv++;
    }
    for(i=(nrig-1); j>0; i++){
        v[k]=m[i][j];
        *nv++;
    }
}
void outputVettore(int v[], int nv){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<nv;i++){
        printf("|%d|", v[i]);
    }

}
```

Sorry for the italian Output and for the bad english.

Comment: `*nv++` increments the pointer, not the value that it points to. Try `(*nv)++;`

Comment: i've tried it but i still get segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs in 
`void bordi(int m[][VAL], int ncol, int nrig, int v[], int *nv)` function.

Fix 3rd and 4th `for` loops conditions. You incremented `j` in first loop but didn't decrement or set it to 0, so you get an infinite loop.

Comment: It actually worked, i can't upvote you so I hope a thanks is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The line in your program `*nv++;` increments the pointer which is totally wrong in logic, try incrementing the value .
that is, Try :-
`(*nv)++;`

Comment: i've tried that but i still get segmentation fault.

Comment: please mention what compiler you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in function `bordi()`. Look at this `for` loop:

```
for(j=(ncol-1); j>0; j++){
    v[k]=m[i][j];
    *nv++;
}
```

The loop control variable `j` initialize with `ncol-1` and checking for condition `j>0`. After executing the loop statements, the `j` will be incremented by `1` (`j++`). So the loop condition `j>0` will always `true` *[until the `j` overflows]* and after few iterations your program starts accessing invalid value of array `m` (`m[i][j]`) which is causing the segmentation fault.

To fix this problem, replace `j++` with `j--` in the loop.

The same problem exists in the next `for` loop as well but in a little different way:

```
for(i=(nrig-1); j>0; i++){
    v[k]=m[i][j];
    *nv++;
}
```

here, in the loop condition you are using variable `j`.
You need to do two changes in this `for` loop.

```
for(i=(nrig-1); i>0; i--){
                ^^   ^^
```